# formatting comma delimited string

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a function or method of dealing with comma-delimited fields?

I have one field in my dataset that looks like this:

```
 Steelers, Cowboys, Patriots, Ravens
```

Is there a way to remove the commas, and display like this?

```
Steelers
Cowboys
Patriots
Ravens
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `REPLACE` function.

```
=REPLACE(Fields!CommaDelimited.Value,", ",vbcrlf)
```

It will produce:

```
Steelers
Cowboys
Patriots
Ravens
```

If `vbcrlf` doesn't work in your case, use `Environment.NewLine`

Also you could use regex in custom code if your field doesn't follow the `", "` pattern.

Let me know if this helps.